Is it possible to emit generic events using assembly?
I'm trying out a proxy / upgrade pattern where the deployed contract is an ERC-721 but it delegates as much functionality to a "controller" contract as possible. The storage is split between them such that all core 721 functionality is in the original deployed contract, but additional functionality can be added to an external and swappable contract that has special privileges on the 721.
For example the 721 exposes a mint(uint256 tokenId, address recipient) function that can only be called by the external contract so that the logic by which mints occur can be updated without losing the canonical 721 contract address. This is different from a proxy pattern because there's no risk of storage conflicts.
Anyway my question is how to make a generic event method so that this external function is able to emit generic events from the 721 (for instance ERC2981 metadata update event). I have the following code with help from chat-gpt but it's failing on the line       calldatacopy(topicsPtr, add(topics.offset, 32), mul(topicsLength, 32)).
Can anyone with better assembly skills help steer me in the right direction?
  function emitGenericEvent(bytes32[] calldata topics, bytes calldata logData) external onlyController {
    require(topics.length <= 4, "Too many topics");
    assembly {
      // Allocate memory for the logData
      let dataPtr := mload(0x40)
      let logDataLength := calldataload(logData.offset)
      calldatacopy(dataPtr, add(logData.offset, 32), logDataLength)

      // Calculate the pointer for topics, ensuring no overlap
      let topicsPtr := add(dataPtr, add(logDataLength, 32))
      let topicsLength := calldataload(topics.offset)
      calldatacopy(topicsPtr, add(topics.offset, 32), mul(topicsLength, 32))

      // Update the free memory pointer
      mstore(0x40, add(topicsPtr, mul(topicsLength, 32)))

      switch topicsLength
      case 0 {
          log0(dataPtr, logDataLength)
      }
      case 1 {
          log1(dataPtr, logDataLength, mload(topicsPtr))
      }
      case 2 {
          log2(dataPtr, logDataLength, mload(topicsPtr), mload(add(topicsPtr, 32)))
      }
      case 3 {
          log3(dataPtr, logDataLength, mload(topicsPtr), mload(add(topicsPtr, 32)), mload(add(topicsPtr, 64)))
      }
      case 4 {
          log4(dataPtr, logDataLength, mload(topicsPtr), mload(add(topicsPtr, 32)), mload(add(topicsPtr, 64)), mload(add(topicsPtr, 96)))
      }
    }
  }


This function would be called by the external function like this:
  function emitMetadataUpdate(uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
    bytes32 topic = keccak256("MetadataUpdate(uint256)");
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(tokenId);
    bytes32[] memory topics = new bytes32[](1);
    topics[0] = topic;
    Speedruns(speedruns).emitGenericEvent(topics, data);
  }
  function emitBatchMetadataUpdate(uint256 _fromTokenId, uint256 _toTokenId) public onlyOwner {
    bytes32 topic = keccak256("BatchMetadataUpdate(uint256,uint256)");
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(_fromTokenId, _toTokenId);
      bytes32[] memory topics = new bytes32[](1);
      topics[0] = topic;
    Speedruns(speedruns).emitGenericEvent(topics, data);
  }
  function exampleEmitMultipleIndexEvent(uint256 _fromTokenId, uint256 _toTokenId) public onlyOwner {
      bytes32 topic = keccak256("BatchMetadataUpdate(uint256,uint256)");
      bytes32 topicFrom = keccak256(abi.encode(_fromTokenId));
      bytes32 topicTo = keccak256(abi.encode(_toTokenId));
      bytes memory data = abi.encode(_fromTokenId, _toTokenId);
      bytes32[] memory topics = new bytes32[](3);
      topics[0] = topic;
      topics[1] = topicFrom;
      topics[2] = topicTo;
      Speedruns(speedruns).emitGenericEvent(topics, data);
  }


This works for me:
function emitGenericEvent(bytes32[] calldata topics, bytes calldata logData) external onlyController {
    require(topics.length <= 4, "Too many topics");
    assembly {
        // Allocate memory for the logData
        let dataPtr := mload(0x40)
        let logDataLength := logData.length
        calldatacopy(dataPtr, logData.offset, logDataLength)

        // Updating the free mem pointer (probably not needed)
        mstore(0x40, add(dataPtr, logDataLength))

        let topicsLength := topics.length
        switch topicsLength
        case 0 {
            log0(dataPtr, logDataLength)
        }
        case 1 {
            log1(dataPtr, logDataLength, calldataload(topics.offset))
        }
        case 2 {
            log2(dataPtr, logDataLength, calldataload(topics.offset), calldataload(add(topics.offset, 32)))
        }
        case 3 {
            log3(dataPtr, logDataLength, calldataload(topics.offset), calldataload(add(topics.offset, 32)), calldataload(add(topics.offset, 64)))
        }
        case 4 {
            log4(dataPtr, logDataLength, calldataload(topics.offset), calldataload(add(topics.offset, 32)), calldataload(add(topics.offset, 64)), calldataload(add(topics.offset, 96)))
        }
    }
}

The mistake you were doing is confusing calldata's .offset and .length: with .offset you get a pointer to the start of actual data, with .length you get the length of data (in bytes for bytes type, or array length for an array type).
Also you were copying the topics to memory then doing mload. That was technically ok but inefficient, it's better to just use calldataload.

I know you're not supposed to use comments to say thank you, but thank you so much @0xsanson
